# Change color of panel based on label in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I would like to change the color of my panel based on the panel title. I have a simple visualization of the tally of healthy and unhealthy.

The word "healthy" in the panel title is a dynamic value determined by a variable name $status.

[image: I made it dynamic by]

However, I want to change the color of the background if the value of $status is unhealthy.

Something, like this

[image]

I tried to do it by value mapping but nothing is happening. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do it based on title. But you can do it based of value, I suppose.

Comment: What is your current query used in this panel?

Comment: My query is ```count(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{} $status)```. status here is either >0 or <1 for health and unhealthy

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do based on variable in general. But in this exact case you can accomplish it by employing this trick: create a query for every value of `$status` and make this query return value only if expected value of `$status` is selected. Then add override for every query and specify color for each.

Create two queries in your panel:

1. Healthy:

```
count(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{} $status) and on() up $status
```

It will return value only if `$status` is `>0`

2. Unhealthy:

```
count(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{} $status) and on() 1-up $status
```

It will return value only if `$status` is `<1`

Then add override configuration for those two queries setting appropriate color for them.

---

Bonus:

Queries for three values of `$status` as in your previous question:

```
count(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{} $status) and on() up+1 $status
#healthy (>0)
count(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{} $status) and on() (1-up $status unless up+0.5 $status)
#unhealthy (<1)
count(azure_metric_loadbalancer_heartbeat{} $status) and on() up+1.5 $status
#all (<2)
```